# How to begin this problem in abstract algebra? What information do I have from fixed things?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $a = (x_1, x_2,... , x_m)(x_{m+1})\dots(x_n)\in S_n$ (so $x_{m+1},\dots, x_n$ are fixed). Find all elements of $S_n$ that commute with $a$.

Do fixed thing commute with anything or do I need to focus only on $(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)$?

I kind of understand how to do this for $S_5$ but this problem has me questioning everything.

I am a beginner and have just gotten into this.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask if fixed points commute with anything, because fixed points are not functions - they're things you plug into functions! Anyway, one thing you want to prove is that if $b$ commutes with $a$, then $b$ fixes the set $\{x_{m+1},\cdots,x_n\}$ (and hence permutes those elements arbitrarily). The question then is what $b$ can do to the set $\{x_1,\cdots,x_m\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the usual cycle notation $a = (1\ 2\ \dots\ m)$ for the permutation $a\in S_n$ with $1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3 \mapsto \dots \mapsto m\mapsto 1$ and $k\mapsto k$ for $k>m$. We are looking for $b\in S_n$ with $ab=ba$.
Evaluating this at $k>m$ we get
$$
a(b(k)) = b(a(k)) = b(k),
$$
so $b(k)$ is a fixed point of $a$ and hence $b(k)>m$ as well. So all $k>m$ have images $b(k)>m$ and $b$ restricts to separate bijections on $\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $\{m+1,\dots,n\}$. What happens on $\{m+1,\dots,n\}$ is irrelevant to $ab=ba$ being satisfied.

For $k\le m$ let us equip $\{1,\dots,m\}$ with addition modulo $m$ so that $a(k)=k+1$ and $ab=ba$ yields
$$
b(k)+1 = b(k+1).
$$
Setting $q=b(1)$ this yields:
$$
b(2)=q+1,\ b(3)=q+2,\ \dots\,b(m) = q+m-1.
$$

We conclude that $b\in S_n$ commutes with $a$ if and only if it cyclically shifts the elements of $\{1,\dots,m\}$ and arbitrarily permutes the elements of $\{m+1,\dots,n\}$.